# Get most recent 8PM via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

What's a good way to get the most recent 8 PM in SQL? For instance if it was 7/17 4 PM result would be 7/16 8PM, but if it was 7/17 9 PM it would be 7/17 8 PM.

Thanks!

Comment: only if you post the way you tried people will be ready to help. Please post your query.

Comment: I'm not to good with datetime stuff in SQL, I was trying it with some kind of GETDATE() and formatting shenanigans but I don't really know what to do

Comment: Hmm now that I think about it DATEDIFF is probably a good way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so:

```
select (case when datepart(hour, getdate()) >= 20
             then cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + 20.0/24
             else cast(cast(getdate() - 1 as date) as datetime) + 20.0/24
        end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It says that `'hour' is not a recognized built in function` though on the hour(getdate()) line (TSQL, Microsoft SQL Server 2008)

Comment: @Hershizer33 . . . I changed that right after I answered.  In SQL Server, you have to use `datepart()` for hours, minutes, and seconds.  You get to use `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` though for the "date parts".  That's not too confusing is it?

Comment: Heh, seems a little overdone but makes sense now that you explain it.  Thanks, the updated query worked perfectly!  I'll accept in a second when it lets me.

Comment: I thought you wanted this to return a datetime as 8pm. The above query does not do that for me. Also, there is some datemath in there without using DATEADD, currently the default for this day but that is not guaranteed to always be that way.

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly you want this to return the closest 8pm. This would return the next day when the time is 8:01 pm on the 17th. I think you would want this to return the 17th?

Comment: The closest 8 PMs Datetime, so this is good (for example right now I just ran it and it returns 2014-07-16 19:59:59.970).  Basically we have a DB sync that occurs at 8 PM, and they have been saying that their changes are now showing up in the reports.  With this query, I can set the result of it to compare against the update time column of the DB and see if their changes were after 8 PM, meaning they haven't been synced yet and should wait for next 8 PM.

Comment: Ahh I was misunderstanding what you wanted, but I think you need to tweak this a little bit. For times during the 8pm hour it will return the current day. It doesn't jump to tomorrow until 9pm.